# redirecting function not working

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, mysqli

i am trying to get password from a login page then trying to gather stored password from mysql. then i am comparing it with submitted password. now i want if the both password match then redirect to a page. but the problem is every time the page redirecting. if the password even doesn't match the page redirecting.

```
<?php
if (redirect()==true){
    header('location:http://google.com');
}
if(redirect()!=false){
    echo "password doesnt match";
}
$hostname="localhost";
$dbname="justlive_main";
$dbusername="justlive_main";
$dbpass="Kalkata1";
#Veriable collected From Login Panel
$Submitted_Email_Address=$_POST['email'];
$Submitted_Password=$_POST['password'];
$encrypt_Submitted_Password=md5($Submitted_Password);

#Lets gather Data From MySql Database
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email_Address='$Submitted_Email_Address'";
$result=$con->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
$SQL_Password = $row['Password'];
function redirect(){
    if ($encrypt_Submitted_Password!=$SQL_Password) {
        return false;
    }
    elseif ($encrypt_Submitted_Password == $SQL_Password) {
        return true;
    }
}
#Lets CLose All The MySql Connection
$result->free();
$con->close();
?>
```

I have removed the function and trying to doing it in simple way. but still its not working. 
Edited code:

```
    <?php 

if ($encrypt_Submitted_Password!=$SQL_Password) {
       echo "Please check your Password";
}
elseif ($encrypt_Submitted_Password == $SQL_Password) {
        header('location:http://google.com');
}
$hostname="localhost";
$dbname="justlive_main";
$dbusername="justlive_main";
$dbpass="Kalkata1";
#Veriable collected From Login Panel
$Submitted_Email_Address=$_POST['email'];
echo "Submited Email Address:". $Submitted_Email_Address."<br>";
$Submitted_Password=$_POST['password'];
echo "Submitted Password : ".$Submitted_Password. "<br>";
$encrypt_Submitted_Password=md5($Submitted_Password);
echo "Encrypted Submitted_Password:".$encrypt_Submitted_Password."<br>";

#Lets gather Data From MySql Database
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email_Address='$Submitted_Email_Address'";
$result=$con->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
$SQL_Password = $row['Password'];
echo "Mysql Database Stored Password: ".$SQL_Password."<br>";


#Lets CLose All The MySql Connection
$result->free();
$con->close();

?>
```

Comment: What is the definition of your `redirect()` function?

Comment: You should have an `exit;` after the `header()` redirect, btw.

Comment: if ($encrypt_Submitted_Password!=$SQL_Password) { this statement should be == NOT =

Comment: @jack i have edited the code as follows. please have a look. still its not working
http://pastebin.com/pFX3kBt2

Comment: sorry i didn't see the ! for != :) disregard my post :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have Checked your code and bring the header command after all the variable loaded. Its working in my end now. I think you called $SQL_Password variable before it ready. Please have a look and let me know if it worked.

```
<?php 
$hostname="localhost";
$dbname="justlive_main";
$dbusername="justlive_main";
$dbpass="Kalkata1";
#Veriable collected From Login Panel
$Submitted_Email_Address=$_POST['email'];
#echo "Submited Email Address:". $Submitted_Email_Address."<br>";
$Submitted_Password=$_POST['password'];
#echo "Submitted Password : ".$Submitted_Password. "<br>";
$encrypt_Submitted_Password=md5($Submitted_Password);
#echo "Encrypted Submitted_Password:".$encrypt_Submitted_Password."<br>";

#Lets gather Data From MySql Database
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email_Address='$Submitted_Email_Address'";
$result=$con->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
$SQL_Password = $row['Password'];
#echo "Mysql Database Stored Password: ".$SQL_Password."<br>";
if ($encrypt_Submitted_Password!=$SQL_Password) {
       echo "Please check your Password";
}
elseif ($encrypt_Submitted_Password == $SQL_Password) {
        header('location:dashboard.php');
}   
#Lets CLose All The MySql Connection
$result->free();
$con->close();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working fine. Thanks a lot for making my code workable without much changing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the redirect() function before $encrypt_Submitted_Password and SQL_Password are set. Move the "ifs" after they are initialized. And you have to declare them global. Or better, pass the the variables as parameters

Answer (score -1):

Your code is

```
if (redirect()==true){
header('location:http://google.com');
}
if(redirect()!=false){
echo "password doesnt match";
}
```

Here meaning of `redirect()==true` and `redirect()!=false` is same

So your code should be

```
if (redirect() == true){
header('location:http://google.com');
}
if (redirect() == false){
echo "password doesnt match";
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, it should be a comment

Comment: Still not a solution to the problem, which is a matter of variable scope and calling order

Answer (score -1):

Your redirect function are not correct: `$encrypt_Submitted_Password` and `$SQL_Password` aren't in function scope, so it will return a **Notice** error, but you can use global for this:

```
function redirect(){

    global $encrypt_Submitted_Password, $SQL_Password

    if ($encrypt_Submitted_Password!=$SQL_Password) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or you can pass both variables as params to function.

And as @Guilleva says, you are calling it before instantiate:

You code should be like this:

```
<?php

function redirect(){
    if ($encrypt_Submitted_Password!=$SQL_Password) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}


$hostname="localhost";
$dbname="justlive_main";
$dbusername="justlive_main";
$dbpass="Kalkata1";
#Veriable collected From Login Panel
$Submitted_Email_Address=$_POST['email'];
$Submitted_Password=$_POST['password'];
$encrypt_Submitted_Password=md5($Submitted_Password);

#Lets gather Data From MySql Database
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email_Address='$Submitted_Email_Address'";
$result=$con->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
$SQL_Password = $row['Password'];

if (redirect()==true){
    header('location:http://google.com');
}else{
    echo "password doesnt match";
}

#Lets CLose All The MySql Connection
$result->free();
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Both you and @Guilleva must have Lynx eyes, that was well spotted!